# How to get div to touch left,using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zLT2.png)

Want div to start on left. Small space do not want.
Tried setting margin and padding to 0 in my div labeled container
and the div itself, nothing changes. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>


<style>
    .container{
    display:flex;
    }

    .box{
    background-color:black;
    }
</style>


<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="box">box</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the body margin to 0

`body {margin: 0}`

https://jsfiddle.net/0b4a6c1b/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `margin: 0` to your body

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.container{
    display:flex;
    }

    .box{
        background-color:black;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="box">box</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to reset on body. I will recommend to use css reset develop by bootstrap called `reboot.css` [reboot](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css) if you not add on start

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
```